# How should I make sure a laptop's CUDA has enabled with 1TFOPS?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

I am looking for a laptop which has 1 TFOPS. could you pls clarify it for me?  I just want to know that how can I make sure a laptop has 1 TFOPS in it or not?

Comment: A simple Google search on the graphic card present in the laptop should give out a peak floating point performance

Comment: Frankly a bit of an odd benchmark. Why do you specifically need 1TFLOP? Also, as written, this isn't really a hardwarerec question so much as a technical support one.